# Custom sound for notification is not working, added in raw folder

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to show notification with custom sound which I have added in raw folder. It is giving default sound instead of mentioned mp3 sound.

```
private void showNotification() {
        //Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            createChannel(notificationManager,getApplicationContext());
        }
        sound = Uri. parse (ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.medicinereminder) ;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Medicine Reminder")
                .setContentText("Have you taken the medicine")
                .setSound(sound);

        notificationManager.notify(101, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

```
private void createChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager, Context context) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION )
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes. USAGE_ALARM )
                .build() ;
        String name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel);
        String description = context.getResources().getString(R.string.description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(name, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        mChannel.setSound(sound,audioAttributes);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
```